# Call method of a class to use instance of another class

Tags: java

I'm more or less new to Java.
My intention is to "export" methods of one class into another class (to have a neat structure of all the methods working with one instance). My problem is that I cannot establish the necessary connection between the instance of my currently overloaded class and the additional methods I put into another class.

So far I've initiated an instance of my class `Graph`and put methods that are just supposed to get values of that instance into `Readings`.
Since I could not figure out much I initiated and instance of `Readings` in `Class`, created a method in `Graph` calling a method in `Readings`.
So far, so good (I assume) but the problem is that the method in `Readings` does not really know how to handle the getters of my `Graph`-Instance/where to access the getters.

```
static Graph graphToBeWorkedOn;
```

in the `Readings` class does not really help and all I get is a nullpointer.

Thanks in advance for any advices/help!

Edit:
`Graph`:

```
...
Readings readingsVariable = new Reading();
...

public List<SpecificNode> methodToBeCalled(int numberInput) {

List<SpecificNode> listOfMethod = new ArrayList<SpecificNode>();
listOfMethod = readingsVariable.methodOne(numberInput);
return listOfMethod;
}
```

`Readings`:

```
...
Graph graphToBeWorkedOn;
...

public List<SpecificNode> methodOne(int numberInput) {

List<SpecificNode> listOfMethod = new ArrayList<SpecificNode>();
...
// fails here with a nullPointer:
graphToBeWorkedOn.getSpecificNode(numberInput)
...


return listOfMethod;
}
```

Initilized a `Graph` in a test-main and attempting to call

```
System.out.println(testGraph.methodOne(2));
```

Comment: Slow down. Classes are not objects. You can send messages to objects, not classes (unless they have static methods). Can you show the code you've produced so far?

Comment: Maybe include some more code, so it's easier to see what you've done (and what might be wrong)...

Answer (score 0):

From your provided code, you never initialize the Graph object.

You'll need to do

```
public List<SpecificNode> methodOne(int numberInput) {
graphToBeWorkedOn = new Graph(); // Initialize Graph
List<SpecificNode> listOfMethod = new ArrayList<SpecificNode>();
...
// Now you can call the method
graphToBeWorkedOn.getSpecificNode(numberInput)
...


return listOfMethod;
}
```

Comment: argh forgot that - I initialize the `Graph` in a `Test`-Main and am attempting to use the method like this:

    System.out.println(testGraph.methodOne(2));

Comment: @grenth The graph being called by the procedure is an instance variable, so if you are instantiating the Graph from the static main method, this will not instantiate the Graph in the Readings class.

Comment: But instantiating a new graph in Readings would not serve the purpose of getting values of the graph I'm working on? Is there an easy way to link an instantiated graph? Could I do it by creating a class instantiating a Graph and Readings and then give any methods/values to this new class and try to deal with input there?

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: use a `Readings` constructor that takes a `Graph` object as parameter and use it to initialize your `graphToBeWorkedOn` field:

in Graph:

```
readingsVariable = new Reading(this);
```

in Readings:

```
Readings(Graph graphToBeWorkedOn) {
    this.graphToBeWorkedOn = graphToBeWorkedOn;
}
```